# Generete Unique Id and pass into text field

Tags: unique, uuid

I am new to php and would like some help on solving a problem I am having. I have a form that has 3 visible input fields, Name, Email address, phone number. Also it includes 3 hidden fields, one is a value set to 2500, the second is a currency, the third needs to be a unique ID. I need help on how to generate a unique id and pass the text/value into a input field in another form. Below is my code. I need the random id to be displayed on the input field merchantid. Thanks

```
<form action="https:urlthathastheform" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="merchantid" name="merchantid" />  
    <input type="hidden" id="currency" name="currency" value="$" />

    <label for="names">Names</label>
    <input type="text" name="names" id="names" />

    <label for="email_address">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address" />

    <label for="phone_number">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" />

    <label for="amount">Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" value="2500" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

php has a function to generate a unique id.

```
<input type="hidden" id="merchantid" name="merchantid" value="<?php echo uniqid();>"/>
```

Note, this id is based on the system clock. http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php